# pandas groupby remove multiple index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a column that I want to groupby and sort by a column value. After groupby I find there are multiple indexes, one of them is the index of origin dataframe, I want to delete this index.

A sample data frame:

```
> d = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                             [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                             [1.25, 10.1, 2.3, 2.4, 1.2, 5.5, 5.7]]).T,
                            columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

> d
    a   b   c
0   0.0 3.0 1.25
1   0.0 4.0 10.10
2   1.0 5.0 2.30
3   1.0 6.0 2.40
4   2.0 7.0 1.20
5   2.0 8.0 5.50
6   2.0 9.0 5.70
```

Function I want to apply:

```
def top_all(df,column='b'):
    return df.sort_index(by=column,ascending=True)
```

How I use groupby:

```
d.groupby('a').apply(top_all)
```

The result I got:

```
        a   b   c
 a              
0.0 0   0.0 3.0 1.25
    1   0.0 4.0 10.10
1.0 2   1.0 5.0 2.30
    3   1.0 6.0 2.40
2.0 4   2.0 7.0 1.20
    5   2.0 8.0 5.50
    6   2.0 9.0 5.70
```

I want to get result like this:

```
        a   b   c
 a              
0.0   0.0   3.0 1.25
      0.0   4.0 10.10
1.0   1.0   5.0 2.30
      1.0   6.0 2.40
2.0   2.0   7.0 1.20
      2.0   8.0 5.50
      2.0   9.0 5.70
```

UPDATED:

I tried `reset_index` with level, but the result didn't contain level. The result I want is in `groupby` format, which means the value of column `a` should be split in different group in index. I don't know if I make it clear...

```
> d.groupby('a').apply(top_all).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
> d
    a   b   c
a           
0.0 0.0 3.0 1.25
0.0 0.0 4.0 10.10
1.0 1.0 5.0 2.30
1.0 1.0 6.0 2.40
2.0 2.0 7.0 1.20
2.0 2.0 8.0 5.50
2.0 2.0 9.0 5.70
```

Comment: `d.groupby('a').apply(top_all).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried reset_index with level, but the result is not what I want, please see my update information.

Comment: How is that not what you are looking for? column `a` is now the only index just like your expected output.

Comment: @Chris The result I want is groupby format, the value of column `a` should be split in different group in index. I don't know if I make it clear...

Comment: That is not how indices work in pandas. They are only displayed that way when you have a multi-index. Even though they are displayed that way the value still exists in that "cell"

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for your explanation, I just want to keep dataframe more readable, since I'll export the dataframe into excel format, split index value into different groups looks more pretty in excel. So it's impossible to obtain the result I want in pandas?

Comment: Might be closer to what you're after if you set `level=0` when you `reset_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of to accomplish this task would be to use `openpyxl`. First save the output to excel with the multi-index using `pandas` then delete the column using `openpyxl` to maintain the format you are looking for.

```
# export multi-index DataFrame to excel
d.groupby('a').apply(top_all).to_excel('python/test.xlsx')

import openpyxl
# open xlsx doc
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('python/test.xlsx')
# use active sheet
sheet = book.active
# delete col
sheet.delete_cols(2)
#save book
book.save('python/test.xlsx')
```

[image]

If you do not want the index name displayed in excel (you will currently have duplicate columns: 'a'):

```
group = d.groupby('a').apply(top_all)
group.index.names = [None, None] # set index names to None
group.to_excel('python/test.xlsx')

# open xlsx doc
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('python/test.xlsx')
# use active sheet
sheet = book.active
# delete col
sheet.delete_cols(2)
#save book
book.save('python/test.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris! it seems like the only way to do that, I'll take that as my solution.